# how to get custom (chrono) timer work with sleep_until?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a custom timer template which i want to use in `std::this_thread::sleep_until()`. So my `now()` method looks like this:

```
static time_point now() {
    return time_point(timer_T::now() - epoch_);
}
```

where **epoch_** is initialized with `timer_T::now()`. Now i want to be able to sleep_until a specific timepoint.

```
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(my_timer<>::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

I think my problem is that i have to make `time_point` with my_timer<> as (template) [Clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) argument, but then there is now conversion between the different time_points. something like:

```
 using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_timer<timer_T>>;
```

The code can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/004e81fe83ff092c).

How can i make this get to work? Also, is there a small chrono howto out, where i can find some information how to create a custom timer?

Comment: You are changing the meaning of time_point, it had to store duration since epoch by definition. If you are not following the rule, API that depends on that cannot work. Create your own completely different time point class with implicit conversion to a real time_point.

Comment: true, but epoch is not defined in the standard, so i thought creating a own clock should be the way, since time_point is based on the clock you give as template parameter.

Comment: Yes, creating your own clock is ok, and it can use whatever epoch it needs. "epoch" does not mean "midnight of the first day of 1970"; that's what "the UNIX epoch" is. "epoch" means, quite simply, "reference date".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at sleep_until, it uses the clock template argument of the time_point to query the current time. So, here is the correct way to define the time point in your code :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

template<typename timer_T = std::chrono::steady_clock>
class my_timer {
public:

    using timer_type = timer_T;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_timer, typename timer_T::time_point::duration >;
    using duration   = typename timer_T::duration;
    using rep    = typename duration::rep;
    using period     = typename duration::period;

    static const bool is_steady = timer_T::is_steady;

    static time_point now() {
        return time_point(timer_T::now() - epoch_);
    }

private:
    static typename timer_T::time_point epoch_;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::time_point my_timer<T>::epoch_ = T::now();


int main(int, char*[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        std::cout << my_timer<>::now().time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_until( my_timer<>::now() + std::chrono::seconds(3) );
    }
}
```

Working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18f7b658e8ee8bd8).

Comment: actually i've tried this, but the problem was, it didn't work as well. now it still not working in **visual studio 2013**... |( i tried using boost chrono and it's fine... i think there is also an issue (again) with the implementation with std::chrono for msvc.

Comment: Just looked at the implementation of VS2013, yes, it is not compliant… I suggest you to fill a bug report on Microsoft connect.

Comment: [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/841208/custom-chrono-clock-issue-with-sleep-until) it comes.